# Question about the tangent plane in $\mathbb{R}^m$

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, derivatives

> Suppose that $M\subset \mathbb{R}^m, m\geq 2$ such that $a\in M$ and
> $a$ is a limit point of $M$.
>
> **Definition.** Plane $H$, which passes through the point $a$ is called tangent plane to $M$ at point $a$, if
> $$\text{dist}(x,H)=o(\lVert x-a\rVert) \quad \text{as} \quad x\to a,
>  x\in M.$$

One can prove the following

> **Theorem.** Suppose that $F$ is continuous in some neighborhood of $a\in \mathbb{R}^m$, differentiable at point $a$,  and
> $\text{grad}F(a)\neq 0$. Then equation $\langle
>  x-a,\text{grad}F(a)\rangle=0$ defines a a tangent plane to level set
> $$M=\{x\in X: F(x)=F(a)\}.$$

We need the continuity of $F$ in some neighborhood of $a$ to show that $a$ is a limit point of $M$.

I understood the proof of this theorem very well but the following Corollary confuses me a bit.

> **Corollary.** If the function $f$ is differentiable at point $a=(a_1,\dots,a_m)$, then its graph at point $(a,f(a))$ has the
> tangent plane which is given by equation $$y-f(a)=\langle
>  \text{grad}f(a),x-a\rangle.$$

I understand the proof of the Corollary also. But since it follows from Theorem (in Theorem we assume that $F$ is continuous in some neighborhood of $a$), then we also need to assume that $f$ is continuous in some neighborhood of $a$ also. I know that it is a bit technical question but I'd be very thankful if someone can tell me is my remark correct or not?

Comment: So you are worried about $f$ being differentiable at $a$ but not continuous in a punctured open disk around $a$?

Comment: @Randall, exactly. I think that it should be also continuous in an open disk around $a$ also.

Answer (score 1):

You can find examples of differentiable functions at one point but not continuous in a neighborhood, such as:
$f(x) = x  \hspace{0.3cm} if \hspace{0.3cm} x  \in \mathbb{Q}, \\
f(x) = -x  \hspace{0.3cm} if  \hspace{0.3cm} x \in \mathbb{R} - \mathbb{Q},$

that is differentiable in $x = 0$ but not continuous in any neighborhood. 
EDIT: Since the continuity in a neighborhood hypothesis is used in the Theorem only to prove that $a$ is a limit point of the level set $M = \{x \in \mathbb{R}^m | F(x) = F(a)\}$, for the function defined by $G(x,y) = F(x) - y$ you could still find the tangent plane even if the function is only differentiable in $a$: indeed, from definition of differentiability of $F$, $a$
is a limit point of $X$ (domain of $F$)
. When you check for the level set $N = \{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^{2m} | G(x,y) = F(x) - y = 0\}$ (i.e. the graph of $F$), $G$ is differentiable at $(a,F(a))$ and $(a,F(a))$
is a limit point of $N$
also (otherwise $F$
would not be differentiable), and you can find an oblique tangent plane that satisfies the definition. The thing is that probably it is not very useful... what do you think?

Comment: If you want I can actually upload the whole proof. Please let me know are you interested or not?

Comment: Yes! Instead of uploading it, you can also give me the reference, no worries! Thanks!

Comment: It turns out that the book has been translated into English so I am sure you can find it.  “smooth functions and maps” by Makarov and Podkorytov.

Comment: Please let me know if you have any updates. I am ready to discuss that!

Comment: Hi! Sorry for the late reply. In the theorem, the continuity in a neighborhood is used to show that a
 is an accumulation point for the level set M. Without this assumption, theoretically you could build examples of functions differentiable at one point but with a
 not being an accumulation point of M. I tried, but until now I have failed. If such an example exists, then the theorem would be valid without any other hypothesis other than differentiability at the point $a$ and the authors would have loosened the theorem's hypotheses. Probably it isn't simply explicitly stated in the Corollary.

Comment: So you mean corollary also should contain the condition of continuity in a neighborhood of $a$?

Comment: Yes, but you need to prove that $(a,f(a)$ is also a limit point of the level set $M = \{  z=(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^{2m} | F(x,y) = f(x) - y = 0 \}$, and without continuity in a neighborhood is not automatically true.

Comment: @ZFR I checked again the book you mentioned. Theoretically you could find the tangent plane even if the function is only differentiable in $a$: indeed, from definition of differentiability, $a$ is a limit point of $X$. When you check for the level set mentioned in the previous comment, $(a,f(a))$ is a limit point of $M$ also (otherwise $f$ would not be differentiable), and you can find an oblique tangent plane that satisfies the definition. The thing is that probably it is not very useful... what do you think?

Comment: I am wondering can you write this properly in your answer(not in comments)? I think it would be useful for others as well. Then I can accept your answer!

Comment: Will do it right now! Thanks!

Comment: You are writing that “indeed, from definition of differentiability,
$a$ is a limit point of $X$”. Which differentiability you mean here?

Comment: You are right, I meant differentiability of $F$, sorry. But please do not accept my answer, I don't consider it satisfactory :(

Comment: I read your answer. Indeed, it is not answering my question yet.